# if/else jQuery with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement

My JSON includes some pictures. I have gotten the pictures to work when they should and when they shouldnt. With the help of a if/else in jQuery. Now what I want to do is that if a image is displayed, so will some text. I want the `foto` the be dispalyed only if a image is displayed. The code below does not work.

The question is: I want the `foto` in JSON only to be displayed when `image` is.

```
var titel = post.titel;
var content = post.content;
var date = post.date;
var author = post.author;
var foto = post.foto
var image = post.image;


  // if a image is going to be displayed
 if (image.length >= 1){
 img = '<img src="/images/' + image+'" alt="image">';
 if (foto.length >= 1){
    renderfoto = foto;
} else{
    renderfoto = "";
}
// else if a image should not be displayed
}else{
img = "";
renderfoto = "";
}
```

This is how the JSON is displayed. It works.

```
var postcontent = '<div class="content-grid-info">'+img+'<div class="post-info"><h1>'+titel+' </h1><h3>Datum: '+date+' Author: '+author+' Photo: '+foto+' </h3><p>'+content+'</p></div></div>';
posts.append(postcontent);
```

JSON had alot of information but I will show you 2 different kinds of

```
{
"posts": [{ 
    "titel": "Blogginlägg 14",
    "content": "'Give it a little touch. Give it a little push push. Caress    it, very gentle.'",
    "date": "2016-11-03",
    "author": "Åsa",
    "foto": "Bo Morenius bmbild.se/",
    "image": "post4.jpg"
    },{
    "titel": "Blogginlägg 9",
    "content": "There are no limits here, start out by believing here. (Points at the heart)",
    "date": "2016-11-03",
    "author": "Åsa",
    "image": ""
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I your example you seem to have foto empty in any case, in your if/else statement. How would you display that then?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Do you mind adding the JSON for us?

Comment: Also include some code that should render something. How do you want foto to be displayed? Where?

Comment: You're using the same variable `foto` for `post.foto` and for the foto that you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different variable for the foto that you want to render than the variable that contains `post.foto` (just like you have `img` for the rendered image, and `image` for `post.image`.

```
var foto = post.foto
var image = post.image;

// if a image is going to be displayed
if (image.length >= 1){
    img = '<img src="/images/' + image+'" alt="image">';
    if (foto.length >= 1){
        renderfoto = foto;
    } else{
        renderfoto = "";
    }
// else if a image should not be displayed
}else{
    img = "";
    renderfoto = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display the posts and if they have an image, you want to display that.

I assigned your JSON to the variable data and then loop through the posts array.

```
var data = {
"posts": [{ 
    "titel": "Blogginlägg 14",
    "content": "'Give it a little touch. Give it a little push push. Caress    it, very gentle.'",
    "date": "2016-11-03",
    "author": "Åsa",
    "foto": "Bo Morenius bmbild.se/",
    "image": "post4.jpg"
    },{
    "titel": "Blogginlägg 9",
    "content": "There are no limits here, start out by believing here. (Points at the heart)",
    "date": "2016-11-03",
    "author": "Åsa",
    "image": ""
    }
]
}

data.posts.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.image) {
    console.log(el.image);
        //or do something else with the image
  }
});
```

Now you can create a div element and append it to the DOM. For example you could do something like this:

```
data.posts.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.image) {
    var postcontent = '<div class="content-grid-info">'+el.image+'<div class="post-info"><h1>'+el.titel+' </h1><h3>Datum: '+el.date+' Author: '+el.author+' Photo: '+el.foto+' </h3><p>'+el.content+'</p></div></div>';
  } else {
    var postcontent = '<div class="content-grid-info">'+el.image+'<div class="post-info"><h1>'+el.titel+' </h1><h3>Datum: '+el.date+' Author: '+el.author+' </h3><p>'+el.content+'</p></div></div>';
  }
  posts.append(postcontent);
});
```

Comment: What I really want is that "foto": should be displayed if "image": is. So if "image": "post4.jpg" I want the   "foto": "Bo Morenius bmbild.se/" to be shown. If "image": "" then "foto": "Bo Morenius bmbild.se/" wont be shown. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Edited answer to better fit your query. It now displays what you want. Not sure if you want the image in the else statement if there is no image...

Comment: So I should replace the entire if/else with the forEach you made?